# How Jewish would this gentile's explanation of the problem of evil be?

Tags: theology

This is my personal explanation of why there is evil in the world. I don't believe evil contradicts a loving G-d, I believe it is evidence for a loving G-d. I will explain my point of view and would like to know how compatible it is with Judaism?

First of all I do believe that G-d could remove all the evil in the world, but it would come at a cost. If G-d wanted to remove all evil in the world he would have to create a puppet humanity. One that just hops to his commands like puppets on a string. Like the ones we used to see on children's play theatre.

If he would do this the evil G-d hypothesis would have legs. Free will unfortunately must allow people to do bad as well as good for the will to be free. G-d gives humanity clear instructions on morality, but gives humanity the choice to do good and bad because he wants followers that choose to have Him in his life even if that means that there are those who choose not to.

Slavery and love don't mix. If you are forced to love someone then that is not really love in my opinion. All our lives revolve around a series of choices. Good ones and bad ones. The fact that we are free to make these choices is to this gentile the greatest gift G-d ever gave humanity. It is just so unfortunate that more people in the world don't exercise this free will to improve the lives of others.

Comment: The Rambam more or less says what you say, so yes you’re idea would seem to be a Jewish one. Check out his Guide to the Perplexed Part 3 Chapters 10-12 in which he addresses evil: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.10?lang=en

Comment: Yes, I don't see any issue with this. Very perceptive of you. A parable I once heard - "my wife decides everything in our relationship, she picks where we live, what synagogue I go to, which shoes I wear, but the one thing she can't choose for me, is _to be in the relationship_". If she did, I wouldn't be her husband, I'd just be her robot. If God _made_ us choose Him, we wouldn't be "someone else". We'd just be Him.